# Why do I get a traceback error when importing my own modules?

Tags: python-3.x, module, python-import

When I tried to import one of my modules such as from the file call.py:

```
def call_name1(name) :
    print(name.title(), 'is present!')
```

Into the test file test.py:

```
import call

call_name1('kevin')
```

It gives me a traceback error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kahsengho/PycharmProjects/Projects/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    call_name1('lebron')
NameError: name 'call_name1' is not defined
```

What have I done wrong? Because I have placed these two files in the same folder.

Comment: you better try from call import call_name1

Answer (score 0):

I found a working code for this!

```
import call

call.call_name1('Kevin')
```